# What is exactly a void?

Tags: guilty-crown

In Guilty Crown, the void is said to be the physical manifestation of a person's "heart", but later on it is also said that it is a fragment of the soul of Mana.

What is exactly a void (besides a McGuffin)?

Comment: I can't quite remember where void is mentioned to be a fragment of Mana's soul. Would you mind citing the episode number?

Comment: @nhahtdh Roger wilco! I have to get home, streaming sites don't open here.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Void Genome](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Genome) page in GC wiki, a Void is said to be

> a person's inner psyche taking physical form.

moreover,

> A Void's form and function reflects the person's fears and or complexes, in other words it's like the shape of their heart, or personality.

The *definition* of void wasn't given explicitly, but from what can be read in the quotes above the Void is the shape taken by the personality of a person infected with the [apocalypse virus](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Virus) after it has been "condensed" by the power of kings.

In the page dedicated to the virus, the stages of the disease are reported:

- Stage 1-2: Virus materializes the mind in the form of a Void.
- Stage 3: Small crystal protusions emerge from the skin and grow along the skin.
- Stage 4 onwards: The person appears to have crystalline substances over some parts of their body. That continues to spread till their entire body is covered in crystals.
- Final Stage: Once the body is completely crystalized the body begins to break down.

So the Void is some kind of temporary materialization of the genome of any individual, which forms after said individual contracts the Apocalypse virus. It takes a shape which mirrors the individual's personality and doesn't really exist unless it is extracted using the power of kings.

The fact that a Void is a fragment of Mana's soul should be a consequence of the fact that she was the first one who contracted the virus.