# What does Shu's void tell us about his personality?

Tags: guilty-crown

In Guilty Crown, Shu finally uses his own void in the end (last episode, if not mistaken). A void is basically a physical manifestation of a person's heart. So what does Shu's void (I'm not mentioning what his void is, for the fear of spoiling it for someone), really tell us about his character and personality ? Also Inori's void being the huge 'Singer's Sword', would reflect  a bold and aggressive personality, whereas she is the exact opposite of that. So how exactly do the voids reflect the person's character and nature(if they do, at all..) ?

Sorry about multiple questions, but I feel they are too closely interrelated to be asked separately.

Comment: Ideally should have the answer here... https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14243/what-is-exactly-a-void But only houses an incomplete answer

Comment: @Arcane Yes I saw that but I felt it didn't really answer my question completely... For instance what does Inori's void tell us? I mean what can we infer from it about her nature and character. And what about Shu's void. I just want to know with respect to both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, Shu's void isn't actually representative of individual strength at all or wanting to take on others burdens although I will admit that he does try to do this a lot.

I think Shu's void is actually more indicative of his character being highly dependent on others to provide him with some initiative or resolution to act. If we take multiple examples from the series and the way that it was structured in that each new trial practically requires a new void to be used or a combination of pre-existing voids. I'd also like to extend this to Shu's character being on to find some compromise or mediate (to some degree) between others as his void activation relies on some form of acceptance of the other party. The void must generally willingly be given by the owner to be used (tbh, this was my interpretation and I do know that in a few instances there was forced use but thats a different discussion).

Tldr: Shu's void indicates he can be described as cooperative and submissive at least in line with my previous point. As the series goes on he loses this submissiveness and becomes willful if not arrogant but eventually humbled by the events. I think the final episodes really stress he needs others and he settles down to an almost meek attitude about his relationships with others.

On a deeper level I'd say that as Shu is the main character and given the way his void works with others is that the message of co-dependency of all members of society for the achievement of a specific goal. Furthermore given that his Void is the 'Power of the King' there can be two further interpretations:

1. the power of the king is a absolute power that can manipulate, order, influence and control others.
2. the power of the king by itself is useless as it is dependent on the acceptance of it by its subjects, and through that acceptance, conformity with the kings demands.

Sadly I can't say much for Inori except that I do think she is quite bold in that her ambitions and willingness to be party to certain things for the sake of a goal is a standout feature of hers. She's willing to take on a fair bit of burden.

Take my answer for what you will, it's also quite likely i'm completely wrong :P

Comment: Finally someone answers my question properly with some deep understanding. Thanks. Actually the two points you have made separately make a lot of sense.

Comment: I do think that the stuff I mentioned is the point of the 2nd half, just wish they did it better since the first 12 episodes were well executed :p

Answer (score 0):

> Also Inori's void being the huge 'Singer's Sword', would reflect a bold and aggressive personality, whereas she is the exact opposite of that.

No, she's actually not far from that at all.

> I mean, she did transform into a half-monster thing in one of the episodes and destroyed "Endlave" robots by herself.

Probably portrays the simple and minimalistic outward appearance while still being dangerous and sharp when used as a weapon. The name "Singer's Sword" is probably just there because she sings (EGOIST is still quite popular to this day).

Now Shu.

> I believe Shu's void (shoe lol) 'transfer' the void of others to make his own set of some kind of arsenal where he can just use whatever he wants at any given time, which can be seen in the last episode where he uses different voids without having to extract them every time. We could conclude this as follows: Void Extraction > Void Storage (and when he desired so) > Void Usage. I believe he can only use one at a time too.

Of what this portrays also was explained in the anime I believe.

> He takes in the emotions of his friends (and foes), all of them, he wants to shoulder them all. Along those lines.

Comment: Could you also provide some adjectives that can be used for Shu and Inori, based on their voids ?

Answer (score -1):

So I like to think his void is one that not only takes in other's burdens (voids) but also enhances them. If you look, every void he uses from that point on seems to be stronger and enhanced (look at the blue and black designs).